# React setState prevState parameter and Array#map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I've encountered a problem with the immutability of the state. Briefly, the Component's state has "persons" array of objects, each of them has a name property, which value I can update on onChange event. 
Here is the updater

```
nameChangedHandler = (event, id) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const persons = this.state.persons.map((pers) => {
      if (pers.id === id) {
        pers.name = value;
      }

      return pers;
    });

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      console.log(prevState);
      return {
        persons
      }
    });
  }
```

This code works well for me and updates name property of a certain person, but I noticed that this.setState function mutates previous state.

I'm guessing that the reason may be in the map function. But how can it be? As far as I know, map takes the previos array and returns a new one. And this new array is later assigned to the persons property as a whole new array in setState function

Comment: Can you please check my answer and give feedback? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map` creates a new array, but the object inside the array are still reference to the state's object.

One approach is to shallow copy the state's object to the new array:

```
const persons = this.state.persons.map( pers => {
  // Do the shallow copy
  if (pers.id === id) {
    return {
      ...pers,
      name: value
    };
  }

  // Return the reference, because we don't do any mutations
  return pers;
});
```

The above approach would work correctly, only if the Person objects are primitive values. Otherwise, you should do a deep copy.

Also you can check [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) for **safer** dealing with immutable processing.

Comment: I'm not sure word "simpler" is a proper one for [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) :D.

Comment: Agree! Changed simpler->safer. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem. Thank you! I forgot that we pass reference to the object in variables. 

But! I thought that React protects the state from changing via simple assignment to the state property (Error: Do not mutate state directly), it requires using setState function instead.

Comment: Thus, I thought that Array#map wouldn't change it. // My wild guess is that React protects only child properties of the state, not the child properties of the state's properties

Comment: Glad I supported you. I haven't seen such mutation warnings that can protect you. I would recommend you to read about shallow and deep copying of JS obects. There you will understand better about child/nested properties mutations.